# GWT-RPC: duplicated server calls

Tags: gwt, rpc, gxt

Last time one of our application hit a strange issue. It happens from time to time (but not regularly) that some GWT RPC calls are duplicated.

Sample from the server logs:

```
2017-04-07 17:11:29,548 DEBUG AuthenticationChecker [ 67] - For: SearchServiceImpl.getDocSearchResults.......................................
2017-04-07 17:11:29,548 DEBUG AuthenticationChecker [ 67] - For: SearchServiceImpl.getDocSearchResults.......................................
```

`AuthenticationChecker` is an aspect that logs above information before every service method call.

As you can see two calls are done exactly in the same millisecond.

Do you have any idea what could case duplicated server calls in GWT/GXT application?

I would be appreciated for any help.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing any of the code... can you share it?

Comment: The code is so complex that it is quite difficult to put here a valuable sample. For the moment I put more logs in the code and if the issue appears again maybe I would be able to discover the origin of the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not the log lines which are being printed twice? We get that a lot. I mean, besides the duplicated lines, have you found any other evidence (side effects, duplicated DB rows, etc.) of the call actually being made more than once?

Comment: Yes, I am quite sure, we have side effect. To do the search we are calling external service and we are doing it in a loop as long as we get requested number of rows ready to be displayed (after calling external service some records can be filter out, then we are calling external service again, and so on) or external service cannot offer more than requested number of rows. Because of duplicated calls one call ends properly and results are displayed to the user, but another one falls into an infinite loop. The problem is that we cannot reproduce the issue to make some more debugging.

Comment: Are you using a proxy between your users and the Java server, and if so, do you have logs to confirm the source of the issue there? I've seen cases where the proxy ends up replaying the request (though can't remember specifics, it has been years). Anything custom in the browser such as plugins? Does it happen to all browsers or perhaps does only one browser have the issue?